# How to fill DataGridView from two tables with ComboBox

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have the two following tables:

```
| Part_id  |   Name  |Part_Type| 
|----------|---------|---------|
|    1     |   ABC   |   Nut   | 
|    2     |   DEF   |   Nut   |
|    3     |   GHI   |  Washer |

|   Type   |   
|----------|  
|   Nut    |
|  Screw   |
|  Washer  |
```

How can I fill a DataGridView like this:

```
| Part_id  |   Name  |     Part_Type     | 
|----------|---------|-------------------|
|    1     |   ABC   |   Nut(combobox)   | 
|    2     |   DEF   |   Nut(combobox)   |
|    3     |   GHI   |  Washer(combobox) |
```

with a combobox with every type on the Part_Type column, so the user may change the type of a specific part?

This is what I have:

```
string myCmdText = "SELECT * FROM Parts";
MySqlCommand myQuery = new MySqlCommand(myCmdText, myConnection);
using (MySqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(myQuery))
{
    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    myAdapter.Fill(DS);
    myDataGridView.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
}
```

I tried casting the Part_Type field cells of the DataGridView as ComboBoxCells and adding the missing part types manually, but I'm getting an invalidcastexception.

Is there a way to do this, preferably easier than the one I tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the dropdown cell type you need to do two things:

- Create cells of type `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`
- Fill them with appropriate data

**Creating drop down cells:**

You have to either create all `Columns` as the types you want them to be in code, instead of using the automatic column generation. Set `myDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;` This needs to be done **before** issuing the query, since you can't change the column type later.

But there is a **workaround**: For later changing the type you have to exchange **each** `Cell` you want to be special, against a cell of the type you want. Note: this is about cells, not columns, so you need to **loop over all rows**, like I do in the code below!

**Filling them with appropriate data:**

You can a) use DataBinding:

- Set the `Datasource` for the ComboBoxCells, usually to a query from the 2nd table; but you could also set them to a select distinct from the first query result or some other source..
- Set `DisplayMember`  & `ValueMember` (in your case to the same field.)

Or you b) could fill the `Items` collection with unbound data.

You can use something like this:

```
string myCmdText = "SELECT * FROM Parts";
string myCmdText2 = "SELECT * FROM Types";
int yourDropdownIndex = 2;
MySqlCommand myQuery = new MySqlCommand(myCmdText, myConnection);
MySqlCommand myQuery2 = new MySqlCommand(myCmdText2, myConnection);
using (MySqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(myQuery))
using (MySqlDataAdapter myAdapter2 = new MySqlDataAdapter(myQuery2))
{
    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    DataTable DT2 = new DataTable();
    myAdapter.Fill(DS);
    myAdapter2.Fill(DT2);
    DS.Tables.Add(DT2);
    myDataGridView.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in myDataGridView.Rows)
    {
        var temp = row.Cells[yourDropdownIndex].Value;
        DataGridViewComboBoxCell comboCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
        comboCell.DisplayMember = "type";
        comboCell.ValueMember = "type";
        comboCell.DataSource = DS.Tables[1];
        row.Cells[yourDropdownIndex] = comboCell;
        row.Cells[yourDropdownIndex].Value = temp;
    }
}
```

If necessary you can now cast a single `Cell` to `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` :

```
int ddlCount = ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell) 
                 myDataGridView.Rows[row].Cells[yourDropdownIndex]).Items.Count;
```

You may want to declare the `DataSet DS` at class level..

Comment: Not quite as easy as changing the column types, which is not possible, but not so hard either.. See my corrections & added commentary! –

Comment: Thanks! This is the code I had to write, unfortunately there is no simpler way to go about it. However, you should not cast a DataGridViewTextBoxCell into a DataGridViewComboBoxCell because it will cause an InvalidCastException, so I would remove that last bit from the answer.

Comment: You can and must do the cast if (and only if) that cell actually is a `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` or else you can't access its special properties, most notably the `Items` collection. So to be on the safe side you may want to check before the cast: `if ( cell.EditType ==  typeof(DataGridViewComboBoxCell)  ) ` .. - Or cast with `as` and check for `null`..

Comment: Yes, I was trying to cast another cell, that's why I got the exception :p... 
Strangely, the dropdown background of the `combocell` is black, I can't find a way to make it the usual white

Comment: Black? Strange, not here. Anything else you do with the cell? Is the text white then??

Comment: It happens when setting `comboCell.ValueMember = "type"`, the background of the dropdown turns black :/ 
If I omit that line it's all good. Thanks!

Comment: Weird but interesting!